# The import sun.security.ec cannot be resolved

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I just started Java in visual studio code.

```
import sun.security.ec.point.Point;

public class Tutorial {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Point point1 = new Point(x:1,y:2);
        System.out.println(point1);
    }
}
```

After run the code, it shows the below warning:

The import sun.security.ec cannot be resolved

Point cannot be resolved to a type

x cannot be resolved to a variable

y cannot be resolved to a variable

Do anyone know why this happen? And anyway to solve this?

Comment: I'd guess you're actually looking for a [`java.awt.Point`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html), and not something from the elliptic curve implementation; as well as the syntax, which looks a bit swifty to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, you are looking for `java.awt.Point`. Moreover, the syntax to initialize `Point` (i.e. `new Point(x:1,y:2)`) is wrong. Do it as follows:

```
import java.awt.Point;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Point point1 = new Point(1, 2);
        System.out.println(point1);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
java.awt.Point[x=1,y=2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need this particular ***import sun.security.ec.point.Point*** ?
May be you were trying to import your own class from different package ?

**Point** from this package **is interface** https://java-browser.yawk.at/java/13/jdk.crypto.ec/sun/security/ec/point/Point.java

Therefore it does not have a constructor.

Syntax `new Point(x: 1, y: 2);` not related to java.

Your code should look like this:

```
public class Tutorial {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int x = 1;
        int y = 2;

        Point point1 = new Point(x, y);

        System.out.println(point1);
    }
}
```